# Why was "this" lost?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will get error accessing the state inside onFormSubmit because when onFormSubmit was
called 'this' was lost. I am not able to find out what happened in render function that made it
loose the 'this' reference to our component class.

1. I know I can resolve this by using arrow function as they take the 'this' from its
   surrounding environment or lexically.
2. Can also be resolved by using bind().

```
      class SearchBar extends React.Component{
        state = {term:  'Hi There'};
        onFormSubmit(e){
            console.log(this.state.term)
            
        }
        render(){
            return (
                <div className="ui segment">
                   <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
                       <label>Image Search</label>
                       <input  type="text" value={this.state.term} onChange={(e) => {
                                                            this.setState({term: e.target.value})
                                                        }}/>
    
                   </form>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: the answers to the question gave the solution but not the logic why it is happening .
If you go to the link all the answers to the question are giving same solution which I pointed out in my question. I just wanted to know why it happens ?

Comment: `this` in Javascript can sometimes seem weird.  If you have come from other languages methods usually contained `data` & `function pointer`, but in JS, the data (this), is often implied.  If you try passing  `obj.method`, all that gets passed is `method`,obj is lost.  eg.  `amethod = obj.method`,, all that amethod contains is method, data will now equal what the current this happens to be, often the global object.  On the other hand if you call `obj.method`, the `this` is implied by JS looking at the `obj.method` as a whole.

Comment: but we did call this.onFormSubmit here this refers to the component ,why we  still lost this?

Comment: Because your basically saying `onSubmit=this.onFormSubmit`, remember how I said you loose `this` when you assign to another var.  So that becomes `onSubmit = onFormSubmit`,  We now have no this, and `onSubmit` 's  `this` will likely be `window` (global).  That why we use `() => this.onFormSubmit` so that the function your passing will have captured the correct `this`.

Comment: To clarify a bit more doing `obj.someMethod()` is fine, because at the point of invocation the this (obj), can be implied.   But whenever your passing `obj.someMethod` around, all that your passing is `someMethod`, obj is lost.